# Flutter integerating Google maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native, dart, flutter

we want to create bicycle sharing project where google map is a must thing
we are willing to use flutter for that how ever it is totally depend on us which platform should be used.i am too much confused which platform should be used.
i have reseach and creating some sample apps in flutter and found that there is stability problems on flutter and integerating with google map is not up to the mark or not too much smart like uber (**we want same look and feel like uber,ofo,uride**).

please suggest which platform should be prefered.

Comment: If you are using react-native, there is fully supported libs called react-native-firbase, react-native-maps and so on, and also had a huge community support, i don't know about flutter that well,

Comment: The plugin is in alpha
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: yes i already knew there things is in alpha mode but stability is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations like the rideshare companies you mention utilize several different Google Maps APIs, so it would go beyond just the google_maps_flutter Package functionality. A common example would be using Directions API[1] and Distance Matrix API, Web Service HTTP requests to generate routes and how long it'll take for all the nearby drivers to get to a user.

That's not to say it isn't possible with using multiple different other plugins (I've seen some for Google Maps Web Services for Flutter here[2]. It would be interesting to see how these applications perform in comparison to native Android; but I'm not sure if there's enough data to say yet.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

[2] https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_webservice